# how to insert value from id to another cell

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have table first column is id and it's unique and auto increment and second column i need the second column if the user input any value will be at second column or the second column will be the same value with id

what i need only is how to write query that will put auto increment value to two cells

here my last try

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table_name';
insert into table_name values(AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT);
```

and it's the error`#1054 - Unknown column 'AUTO_INCREMENT' in 'field list'`

Comment: What is your column name??

Comment: barcode but is it necessary ?

Comment: I don't quite understand, you mean you have `id` and `col2` - on update you want to set `col2` to the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value? Or just the value of `id` ?

Comment: what is the difference the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value will be at `id`

Comment: i just want barcode and id be the same value

Comment: Surely you can just do `UPDATE mytable SET barcode=id` (if you are doing a specific row you can use the selected rows, or the last_id function if just inserted, for a ` WHERE id=?` append)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP this will update all rows right ?

Comment: @robert It will, unless you add a WHERE clause of course

Comment: i want to do it with one query now i will insert the row with values and then update these values it will take double time

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question but I think your select  statement should be something like

```
SELECT `barcode`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table_name';
```

you can update table like this

```
UPDATE table_name SET field1=new-value1, field2=new-value2
[WHERE Clause]
```

Comment: value1 and value2 from the first query ?

Comment: U mean i get value from first query and insert it to the second one but if someone do the same at the same time both will have the same auto increment value to insert into the second